# Auth Change listener in Firebase Auth not listening after pushing Splash screen in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

## The Problem

In my main.dart file, I using the Firebase AuthChange listener to listen for sign in and sign out. But the problem is that when my app is first launched it checks the auth state and returns a splash screen. If the user is logged out, I have a splash screen that pushes the login screen and if the user is logged in, I have a different splash screen that pushes the home screen.
Once any screen is pushed, it doesn't listen to any auth changes because the splash screen has pushed another screen. Is there any way to overcome this or can we integrate the splash screen into the main.dart file?

### My Code

This is the main.dart file

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Main()
    )
  );
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Splash2();
          } else {
            return const Splash();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way I could make the listener listen to the entire app?

Comment: I have encountered same issue. Did you manage to find the solution?